# Non-blocking connect OpenSSL

Tags: c++, c, sockets, openssl

I created a regular C socket. Upon connect, it returns `EWOULDBLOCK/WSAEWOULDBLOCK` as expected because I did:

```
unsigned long int mode = 0;
ioctlsocket(ssl_info->sock, FIONBIO, &mode);
setsockopt(ssl_info->sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&tv, sizeof(tv));
setsockopt(ssl_info->sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char*)&tv, sizeof(tv));
```

to put the socket in non-blocking mode. After that I do:

```
ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock);
return SSL_connect(ssl);
```

However, it returns -1.

I read online that it means I need to handle `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` and `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE`.

so I did:

```
int res = -1;
while(res == -1)
{
    res = SSL_connect(ssl);
    switch (SSL_get_error(ssl, res))
    {
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT:
        MessageBox(NULL, "Connect Error", "", 0);
        break;

        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:   //prints this every time..
        MessageBox(NULL, "Read Error", "", 0);
        break;

        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
        MessageBox(NULL, "Write Error", "", 0);
        break;
    }

    SelectSocket(ssl);
}

std::cout<<"Connected!\n";
```

Where `SelectSocket` is defined as:

```
bool SelectSocket(SSL* ssl)
{
    if (blockmode)
    {
        fd_set readfds;
        fd_set writefds;
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_ZERO (&writefds);
        FD_SET(ssl_info->sock, &readfds);
        FD_SET(ssl_info->sock, &writefds);

        struct timeval tv = {0};
        tv.tv_sec = timeout / 1000;
        tv.tv_usec = timeout % 1000;
        return select(sock + 1, &readfds, &writefds, NULL, &tv) >= 0;
    }

    return select(sock + 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) != SOCKET_ERROR;
}
```

So how exactly can I get it to connect? I can't seem to be able to read or write anything when the socket is non-blocking :S.

Any ideas?

Comment: Setting send or receive timeouts on a non-blocking socket doesn't make sense. You do indeed need to handle WANT_READ and WANT_WRITE. I suggest you do that.

Comment: your function SelectSocket returns bool, but you compare it with -1 - thats probably not great

Comment: Ok I fixed the `-1` thing. Still the same. I'm not sure what the documentation means by handle `WANT_READ` and `WANT_WRITE`. I tried doing a `SSL_read` in the infinite loop; no difference.

Comment: @Brandon,  you mentioned that SSL_connect() returns (-1).  I assume that your code then called SSL_get_error()?  (I don't see that in the code provided).  If so, what did SSL_get_error() return?

Comment: I added the code to the OP.

Comment: @Brandon, the added code is helpful; Thank-you.  Which case was indicated from the SSL_connect() call (ie: SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT, SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ or SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE)?

Comment: `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` is the case that is indicated.

Comment: @Brandon : How did you resolve this issues.I am facing the same issue.. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078038/ssl-connect-produces-1-error ). Request some guidance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (-1) returned by SSL_connect() indicates that the underlying BIO could not satisfy the needs of SSL_connect() to continue the handshake.

Generally, the calling process then must repeat the call after taking appropriate action to satisfy the needs of SSL_connect().

However, when using a non-blocking socket, nothing is to be done; but select() can be used to check for the required condition.

(When using a buffering BIO, like a BIO pair, data must be written into or retrieved out of the BIO before being able to continue.)

Comment: i am facing -1 on ssl_connect - ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078038/ssl-connect-produces-1-error ) .Request your view.

Comment: "but select() can be used to check for the required condition." what is the required condition ?

Answer (score 2):

Your code actually **disables** non-blocking I/O. As you are passing 0 as argument value for FIONBIO to ioctlsocket, which is documented as:

> FIONBIO
>
> > The *argp parameter is a pointer to an unsigned long value. Set *argp to a **nonzero value** if the **nonblocking mode** should be **enabled**, or **zero** if the nonblocking mode should be **disabled**. [..]

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx