# SSL CONNECT produces -1 ERROR

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

I am unable to connect with the SSL server, and not able to locate the error.

Error code returned during `SSL_CONNECT()` is -1 (SSL_SOCKET:Could not build SSL session: 2)

I have read some of forums which suggest to perform `SELECT` confused on the implementation part.

Posted my client code below. Request pointers for trouble shooting:

```
int setupSSL(int server)
{
    int retVal=0;
    if(InitCTX() != 0)
        return -1;
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);      /* create new SSL connection state */
    if(ssl == NULL)
    {            
        sprintf(debugBuf,"SYSTEM:%s_SOCKET:SSL:Unable to create SSL_new context\n",str[server]);
        debug_log(debugBuf,DEBUG_LOG);
        return -1;            
    }

    retVal=SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);    /* attach the socket descriptor */
    if ( retVal != 1 ){   /* perform the connection */
        sprintf(debugBuf,"SYSTEM:%s_SOCKET:Could not set ssl FD: %d %s\n",str[server],retVal,strerror(retVal));
        debug_log(debugBuf,DEBUG_LOG);
        return -1;
    }

do 
{
    retVal =   SSL_connect(ssl);  
    errorStatus=SSL_get_error (ssl, retVal) ;
    switch (errorStatus) 
    {
        case SSL_ERROR_NONE: 
        break;
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
        break;
        default:
    sprintf(debugBuf,"SYSTEM:SSL_SOCKET:Could not build SSL session: %d %s\n",errorStatus,strerror(retVal));
    debug_log(debugBuf,DEBUG_LOG);
    return -1;              
        break;
    }

sprintf(debugBuf,"SYSTEM:SSL_SOCKET:Could not build SSL session: %d %s\n",errorStatus,strerror(retVal));
debug_log(debugBuf,DEBUG_LOG);
retryMaxCount--;
if (retryMaxCount <= 0 )
    break;  
}while ( ssl && errorStatus != SSL_ERROR_NONE );


    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
    if(cert == NULL){

        sprintf(debugBuf,"SYSTEM:%s_SOCKET:SSL:Unable to retrive server certificate\n",str[server]);
        debug_log(debugBuf,DEBUG_LOG);            
    }

    if(SSL_get_verify_result(ssl)!=X509_V_OK){

        sprintf(debugBuf,"SYSTEM:%s_SOCKET:SSL:Certificate doesn't verify\n",str[server]);
        debug_log(debugBuf,DEBUG_LOG);
        return -1;
    }

    X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID (X509_get_subject_name (cert),  NID_commonName,  peer_CN, 256);
    if(strcasecmp(peer_CN, cnName)){
        sprintf(debugBuf,"SYSTEM:%s_SOCKET:SSL:Common name doesn't match host name\n",str[server]);
        debug_log(debugBuf,DEBUG_LOG);
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int InitCTX(void)
{        
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* Load cryptos, et.al. */
    SSL_load_error_strings();   /* Bring in and register error messages */
    if(SSL_library_init() < 0){
        debug_log("SYSTEM:SSL_SOCKET:Could not initialize the OpenSSL library\n",TRACE_LOG);
        return -1;
    }

    method = SSLv3_client_method();  /* Create new client-method instance */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* Create new context */
    if ( ctx == NULL){
        debug_log("SYSTEM:SSL_SOCKET:Unable to create a new SSL context structure\n",TRACE_LOG);
        return -1;
    }

    SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2);
    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx,CertFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
        debug_log("SYSTEM:SSL_SOCKET:Error setting the certificate file.\n",TRACE_LOG);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Set the list of trusted CAs based on the file and/or directory provided*/
    if(SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,CertFile,NULL)<1) {
        debug_log("SYSTEM:SSL_SOCKET:Error setting verify location.\n",TRACE_LOG);
        return -1;
    }

    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx,SSL_VERIFY_PEER,NULL);
    SSL_CTX_set_timeout (ctx, 60);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did the call to `SSL_new()` succeed?

Comment: @DaV : will check and update ,sorry missed that

Comment: @DaV : retVal =   SSL_connect(ssl);  the fail is at this point only..

Comment: This is expected behavior. See the OpenSSL docs at [`SSL_connect(3)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_connect.html).

Comment: You can put Connect in a loop and call select right after until it returns something other than -1. You can also just make the socket non-blocking after connecting.. Another option is to write 1 byte to the socket then call read and it'll connect. I used the select loop with a counter or timeout and it works fine.

Comment: @Brandon : is there any connect snippet with select that you can point me.

Comment: @Ragav http://pastebin.com/SKJVcSRd  That's all I do and it works. You don't need all the timeout stuff. A simple select works fine. Just `select(sock + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);` is best. It's what I use when I don't care about waiting between tries. Way faster than the timeout as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the documentation of the SSL_* functions: You should not use strerror, but `SSL_get_error(retVal)` to get the SSL error code for SSL_connect. Depending on the error code you need to use ERR_get_error to access the error queue and you get use ERR_error_string to get the string representation of errors.

Comment: noted, But, one more query is that i have put socket to non blocking mode..will that have any effect on the connection part??

Comment: @Ragav Documentation of SSL_connect says that `If the underlying BIO is non-blocking, SSL_connect() will also return when the underlying BIO could not satisfy the needs of SSL_connect() to continue the handshake, indicating the problem by the return value -1. In this case a call to SSL_get_error() with the return value of SSL_connect() will yield SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ or SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE.` It means that you need to call again SSL_Connect.